# Opening webapi project giving an error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am getting

> "Creation of virtual directory http://localhost:30852/ failed with the error: Filename: redirection.config Error: cannot read configuration file"

while opening webapi project. Someone else created on their machine and I am downloading from TFS. It works fine on their machine.

[image: error message]

I have installed latest .net framework and I have IIS installed on my local machine.

I already tried opening Visual Studio as admin, but no use.

Comment: Have you checked that your team mate actually checked-in the "redirection.config" file and that you downloaded it and exists in the project folder?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of things gone wrong here.

1) I've seen the problem occurs that TFS ignores an item from checking in or completely removes them from the being part of source control.

If this is the case, let your college re-add then to the source control and commit.

2) check on your college's machine. If the file is actually marked as part of the commit and if it's committed. If both seem fine, make sure the version on your local repo is correctly pulled from TFS.

Depending on what version control (git or TFS) you are using your files are by default located at: `C:\Users\%username%\Source`

3) There is a difference in the redirection config you and your college are using. You might already have the other application registered at this path in your application host config.

The config can be found at `Documents\IISExpress\config` simply compare this config with your colleges. If you have a conflicting configuration you can change it to a different port.

As last resort, you could simply copy over the redirect config from your college and see if this fixes the problem.